# IPFS hash link keep loading without not responding

Tags: go-ethereum, javascript, python, ipfs, swarm

I'm trying to add many JSON files in IPFS using the following API from this liberary [py-ipfs-http-client](https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/py-ipfs-http-client), after running locally `ipfs daemon`:

`client.add('item.json')`

And here is the output of the `item.json` file

`{"name":"Musk","description":"description","image":"https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmP8ZD7YrSyPWaU1UnTD9jFR6rwokncCCd3WK7f7eSJi11/0003.jpeg"}`

The returned hash for this `item.json` works successfully, but when I'm trying to add another JSON file that's slightly different from the first one, the output IPFS hash keeps loading for a long time without any outputs.

And here is the output of the second `item2.json` file

`{"name":"Musk2","description":"description","image":"https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmP8ZD7YrSyPWaU1UnTD9jFR6rwokncCCd3WK7f7eSJi11/0004.jpeg"}`

And that happens also many times if I just changed the name of the value with anything other than "Musk".

And when I try with localhost IPFS domain it works `http://localhost:8081/ipfs/<hash>` but not with the main ipfs link `https://ipfs.io/ipfs/<hash>`

I need your help to understand this behavior.
Thanks.